# How to get small popup with information when moving mouse over product picture in virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, popup, virtuemart

I have a list of product in virtuemart as presented in screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

My client wants to have the following effect: while doing hovering over picture with mouse, he wants popup with full description of product.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include some javascript

```
JHTML::script( 'mytitle.js', 'path/to/my/js' );
```

in the flypage.php

```
components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/product_details/flypage.tpl.php
```

and replace

```
<h1><?php echo $product_name ?> <?php echo $edit_link ?></h1>
```

with something like

```
<h1 title="Produkt Title::Product Description"><?php echo $product_name ?> <?php echo $edit_link ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer! What will be in that javascript?

Comment: There will be some popup JS that takes care of the title attributes and create a hover popup conaining that data. 
You could also include the standard joomla Toolpit mootools behaviour.
It works on `.hasTip` Classes.